# On mobile, how do I fix the OpenTok Call window in place?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

Can anyone tell me how I fix the opentok call window in place on mobile (Tablet & Phone)? At the minute, users can 'drag' it across the screen. When in focus I would like it to be fixed in place.

I don't know if this is a opentok element fix, object fix or CSS fix.

Any helpfull suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: Apparently, it's not an opentok issue but a DIV issue. So, if anyone can help me 'lock' the video call's DIV element in place, please drop me an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `position: absolute`?

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="publisher"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#publisher {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px
}
```

That would fix the publisher `div` on the bottom right of the window.